# Upgraded from WiX 3.10 to 3.11 and .wixproj files show "incompatible" in VS 2013

Tags: wix, wix3

I've upgraded from WiX 3.10 to 3.11 and suddenly I'm unable to build my WiX install. In the solution, the wixproj files show "incompatible". When I go to open the .wixproj file directly, that file tag is not an option. 
I have the target path set to the "v3.x" in the PropertyGroup, as one post suggested. I have also cleared the "Appdata" for VS 12.0, and restarted my machine. I'm still unable to open .wixproj files. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. What solved it for me was making sure that I had the "WiX Toolset Visual Studio [Your Version Here] Extension" installed.